# Saving EObjects in different resources, depending on their content

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

I'm working with an EMF model, which is composed of several `Commands`.

Each command has a boolean attribute named `submitted` which is handled by my application. According to the value of this attribute, I want to save the Command in file "submitted" or in file "toSubmit".  How can I do that?

Since elements to be submitted can refer to submitted elements, I was planning to put them in two resources of the same resourceSet... is this enough for cross-references?

Additionally, I would also like to have a "complete" file, which comprehend both element to submit and those already submitted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more thing: in order to cross-reference, in addition to being saved into the same resourceset the referenced elements have to be saved in a resource already.

In other words, you have to order the saving of the resources wrt the dependencies: first the resource has to be saved, that is not refering to the other, and then the referrer.

Comment: I tried to save my models following your guideline, but I have some problems. By construction, `submitted` elements cannot refer to `queued` ones. Accordingly, I save the model of submitted elements before the other model. However, the first model is saved successfully, but the second model fails by throwing the following exception: `org.eclipse.xtext.parsetree.reconstr.XtextSerializationException: Could not serialize cross reference from Model.commands[1]->FunctionSingle.inputs to Model.commands[1]->VariableContinuous'Var2'
`

Comment: So you are using Xtext - thats new information. :D Well, there are some difference constraints then - I would look at the grammar whether it can store such references. If not, then it cannot serialize it to the Xtext resource.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that... how my grammar (or my model) should be modified to allow such crossreferences? Googling around, I found a post that states that xtext should be able to manage such crossreferences ( http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/174945/#page_top )... but obviously I'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: Could you provide some details about the grammars, and maybe the code generating the models? The best part of it would be in the question as further edit. Without further information it is really hard to guess what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Hi, I found an answer to my problems... I was using a wrong scopingFragment. If you are still interested, you can find the code and the answers here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/241756/